pandas df.dtypes does not identify timestamps data type correctly...?
Edit: I don't see this as a duplicate of the question marked right now. The issue there is about loc and "memory allocation" (how the data is being presented) while in this question it seems to be about mixing different timezones (what the data actually is)...
I have the following pandas dataframe at hand:
          key                    created
0  DLAND-1957  2024-05-23 12:59:25+02:00
1  DLAND-1956  2024-05-22 13:53:09+01:00

it is being created in this way:
import pandas as pd
key = ["DLAND-1957", "DLAND-1956"]
created = ["2024-05-23 12:59:25+02:00", "2024-05-22 13:53:09+01:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"key":key, "created":created})
df["created"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created"])

As you can see, the column "created" is a "timestamp":
type(list(df.iloc[0])[1])
type(list(df.iloc[1])[1])

both return
pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

However,
df.dtypes

returns
key        object
created    object

So just the mere fact that timestamps are present from different timezones makes pandas generalize the type of the column to become "object"? That is a bit problematic when trying to detect data types in a pandas dataframe... how (if not using df.dtypes) do I correctly detect timestamp and other data types in a pandas dataframe?

this 2024-05-23 12:59:25+02:00 looks like timestamp but it doesn't have to be timestamp but string. And column may have also some value which can't be convert to timestamp - like None or np.nan - and then dtypes shows column as object, not timestamp. You checked only one value in column type(list(df.iloc[0])[1])

The timezone is not unified in your output. That's why its dtype is object. Use the utc=True parameter to make sure all the data in the output have the same timezone.

@Timeless Wrong choice of a possible duplicate. This may be the one

@Vitalizzare, my bad, i've linked the right dup now.
